# How can I best handle variable listings with multiple options and keep stock stock levels correct?

Tags: stock, simple-product

I am trying to work out how to best offer 4 new new products that are made up of three main choices (Frame Kits / Wheelsets / Finishing Kits).

1. Bike frame and fork kits or full build (two options)?
2. Aluminium Wheelset or Carbon Wheelset or Non Required (three options)
3. Finishing Kits - everything else needed to complete the mtb (six options)

The reason I am finding this idea so complicated is stock control. As for number 2 in the above list we have 6 different wheelsets to cover all 4 different frames and for number 3 in the list the the 5 different groupsets will go with any frame.

So my question is, is there a better way than making a listing for every combination and watching stock levels manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configurable product and then create associated products as part of this configurable product specifying stock levels. This way you will not need to manage stock manually. There are many tutorials on how to add configurable products, this is first one I got when I googled it, but you should be able to find many more:

https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/

Comment: Thanks for the reply and that would work but would not solve my issue of say wheelset 1 being offered on 3 different frames, the standard configurable product way would not take into account the wheelsets sold with the other frames and I would need to allocate some to each frame. Add on to this the groupset options and stock control goes out the window. I was hoping that I could have a communal pool of simple products which more than one configurable product could pull from.

Comment: OK my answer will not solve this problem. Unfortunately I cannot answer your question right now, but I am voting it up in hope that you will get your answer and at the same time I will learn something valuable.  Take care.